# Determine if input string matches clock time using regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to determine if an input string is in a valid 24-hour date format (ie. hh:mm:ss). I'm using a few different logics and have been mostly successful with my test cases. My code currently fails for all the inputs I've tried (including the ones below).

The expression is supposed to work in the following way:

- Inputting `11:24:10` should output `Valid form`
- inputting `00:13:42` should output `Valid form`
- Inputting `24:52:25` should output `Invalid form`
- Inputting `05:62:55` should output `Invalid form`

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.print("String to check: ");
      String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

      if (input.matches("((0|1)[0-9])|(2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")) {
         System.out.println("Valid form");
      } else {
         System.out.println("Invalid form");
      }
   }
}
```

I've only recently started learning Java and I apologize if this question has been asked before (I googled!). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in your question? How is this code failing (e.g., on which test cases)? On which test cases is it succeeding?

Comment: @Alex It returns Invalid form for all the inputs I tried.

Comment: If your question is really about Regex then you have some good answers. If your question is really about validating time-of-day values then instead of Regex I suggest you use the [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class in the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later (with back-ports to Java 6 & 7 and Android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
(((0|1)[0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

According to your regex

```
((0|1)[0-9])|(2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

It will match `((0|1)[0-9])` or `(2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]`

You can also use `non capturing` group if you just want to match it as

```
(?:(?:(?:0|1)[0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

Your regex can be simplified further as by modifying hours part

```
[01][0-9]
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/HVuMvs)**

**EDIT**

Little bit modification

```
(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN0jR1/1)**

Comment: How does `non capturing` differ from what I've tried to implement?

Comment: @Vishal `non capturing` groups do not capture the data(within brackets`()`)..So if you only want to check whether a string matches with the  regex and you do not want `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` separately then you should use `non capturing groups`

Comment: @Vishal As per your code, it looks you are only trying to match data whether it is in correct format or not. So I suggested you to use `non capturing group`

Comment: I understand the different regex use cases now. Thanks!

Comment: `(?:(?:(?:(?:0|1)[0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])` Would this be more appropriate here? (I added another group(?))

Comment: If you do not want to capture then its ok..but there is no requirement of it..also too many `non capturing group` makes the `regex` too obfuscated

Comment: @Vishal I have added an edit to look little bit less obfuscated

Comment: That's much clearer but why not make the entire string a `non capturing` group? As you said, they are all only being matched with the input.

Comment: @Vishal What's inside `()` are only captured.. So this `[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]` do not gets `captured` anyway.. They are only matched.. So there is no need to use `non capturing group` for entire string

Comment: Oh so all of this has to do with using `()` around code and not having the overhead of being able to read it later. That makes complete sense now.

Comment: @Vishal Actually `captured groups` come in pretty handy because we can access it later in matching.. For further reading :- http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your current regex will match `(0|1)[0-9])` or `(2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]`. You want your `||` operator to work on the `(0|1)[0-9])` and `(2[0-3])`. So what you want is this:

```
((0|1)[0-9])|(2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

You also have a resource leak because you do not close your `Scanner`. It is best to store the new `Scanner` in a variable so that you can close it later. Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("String to check: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        if (input.matches("(((0|1)[0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]")) {
            System.out.println("Valid form");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid form");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the garbage collector took care of `Scanner` objects. I'll make sure to close them from now on. Thanks!